# How to access GPT-3, BERT or alike?

Tags: nlp, gpt, pretraining

I am interested in accessing NLP models mentioned in scientific papers, to replicate some results and experiment.

But I only see waiting lists https://openai.com/blog/openai-api/ and licenses granted in large commercial deals https://www.theverge.com/2020/9/22/21451283/microsoft-openai-gpt-3-exclusive-license-ai-language-research .

How can a researcher not affiliated to a university or (large) tech company obtain access so to replicate experiments of scientific papers ?

Which alternatives would you suggest to leverage on pre-trained data sets ?

Comment: Please, consider marking the answer as correct if deemed so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAI has not released the weights of GPT-3, so you have to access it through their API. However, all other popular models have been released and are easily accessible. This includes [GPT-2](https://openai.com/blog/better-language-models/), [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805), [RoBERTa](https://ai.facebook.com/blog/roberta-an-optimized-method-for-pretraining-self-supervised-nlp-systems/), [Electra](https://openreview.net/forum?id=r1xMH1BtvB), etc.

The easiest way to access them all in a unified way is by means of the [Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) Python library by Huggingface. This library supports using the models from either Tensorflow or Pytorch, so it is very flexible.

The library has a repository with all the mentioned models, which are downloaded automatically the first time you use them from the code. This repository is called the "model hub", and you can browse its contents [here](https://huggingface.co/models).

Comment: Hi @ncasas, thank you I did not know that resource.

Comment: I take the opportunity to ask a question to you, since you're working your PhD : I am not enrolled in University, and came to  interest in data-science from my former startup (I was coming from a different field). I'd like to gain expertise for prototypes and carrying on research on knowledge landscapes. Are there options to establish remote paid internship or fix-term collaborations with researchers / Uni ? I thought, could it be valuable to assist in complementary tasks (e.g. UX, data-curation, software dev) in exchange of supervision?

Comment: I am not familiar with such type of arrangements. I suggest you ask in https://academia.stackexchange.com/